# jquery .load() can't load js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Like the title said,

`.load()` function won't load javascript from called page.

Would be grateful for any tips.

It's basic Single paged interface.

[here](http://nikolafolio.in.rs/SUI.js) is the full code.

Comment: some piece of code would help you to find an accurate answer

Comment: Can you please include some more source - ie what are you trying to load

Comment: Are you trying to load a js file from a different domain than yours?

Comment: Please add some code, some of the errors you're getting, or at least something we can use to help.

Comment: I posted the full code.
Sorry for delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `getScript`:

```
$.getScript("url");
```

This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script", // <===
  success: success
});
```

`getScript` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

---

Based on the code in the edit:

```
var LoadContentWrapper = href+' .pageloader_inner';

$('#pageloader').delay(1000).queue(function() {
    $(this).load(LoadContentWrapper, function() {
```

The url: `href+' .pageloader_inner';` is **invalid**. you need to give the `load` function a valid URL

Comment: Eh that's the only way to call only part of the page..
I kinda got it working with .getScript(), althou' i'm facing some serious issues when the script calls it self.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use  `getScript`
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

> Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP
>   request, then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you specified a page fragment to load and in that case scripts are stripped out

```
//Scripts executeds    
$('#a').load('article.html');
//scripts stripped 
$('#b').load('article.html #target');
```

From the docs

> Script Execution
>
> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If
>   .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and thus are not executed. An example of both cases can be seen below: